# Does SQL Server lock the row after insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server `after insert` trigger that takes row id and sends it to a web service that performs select query on the same row but it seems the operation deadlocked all operation.

Comment: A trigger should be very **small and nimble** - it is generally **not** a good idea to do any long running tasks - like extensive calculations, or calls to external web services etc. You should try to de-couple these long running operations from the trigger

Comment: agreed with @marc_s here. Keep it very simple and lightweight. If you really need to call a web services in a trigger you should look at service broker and asynchronous queues on SQL server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  AFTER INSERT triggers run in the same transaction as the INSERT statement, so the rows affected by the operation will be locked.  Your trigger should insert a row into another table or queue, and have a background process call your web service after the INSERT commits.

Comment: Just to be clear : the **trigger itself** can access the rows inserted - since it's running in the same transaction as the `INSERT` operation. But any "outside" process cannot read those rows (since they are locked) - unless using the `READ UNCOMMITTED` transaction isolation level